# formatting date in android

Tags: android, date, date-format, simpledateformat

I'm trying to display date which I already have to a new format, i'm using `SimpleDateFormat` for this.

**Android Code**

```
String date = "2013-08-11 20:38 EDT";
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm a");
try {
    newDate = sf.format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm z").parse(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It displays :
**11 August 2013 08:38 PM**

However if I run the same code in `JAVA` (as a normal JAVA console application)

**JAVA**

```
String date = "2013-08-11 20:38 EDT";
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm a");
String lDate = sf.format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm z").parse(date));
System.out.println(lDate);
```

It displays :
**12 August 2013 06:08 AM**

This is the format which I need to display.

*P.S.* : I got a warning in android saying

> To get local formatting use getDateInstance(), getDateTimeInstance(), or getTimeInstance(), or use new SimpleDateFormat(String template, Locale locale) with for example Locale.US for ASCII dates.

so I tried adding `Locale.US` to `SimpleDateFormat` it again show the **11 August 2013 08:38 PM** and not **12 August 2013 06:08 AM**

My Question is :
how to display date as 12 August 2013 06:08 AM in android.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: I want my date to be displayed as 12 August 2013 06:08 AM and not 11 August 2013 08:38 PM in android code.

Comment: are you stuck in PM to AM changes?

Comment: Set the timezone explicitly on your date formatters.

Comment: Check your Android Emulator time and local pc time.

Comment: local time in PC is IST, Emulator Eastern Time Zone

Comment: Can use SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm z", java.util.Locale.getDefault()); to remove the warning

Comment: @ShirishHerwade thanks for commenting adding `Locale.getDefault()` solved the problem, which I have mentioned as a comment in the accepted answer :)

Comment: Ohhh... I didn't read that... actually I added that comment, so that it may help some one other having same issue like us :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local time IST is UTC+05:30, your Android time EDT is UTC-04:00. Together they add to 9h30min of difference explaining the difference in output.

Set your Android device to IST timezone to get the same output.

Alternatively, you can call `setTimeZone()` on the `DateFormat` to explicitly set a timezone to use.

It is also helpful to explicitly print timezone information to make datetime stamps less ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks. Setting the Emulator Time Zone to IST solved the problem.

Comment: I also added `Locale.getDefault()` in both `SimpleDateFormat` as a second argument. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.S", Locale.US)
```

You should specify the time zone

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
SimpleDateFormat simple = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm a" , java.util.Locale.getDefault());
```